# sql: how to select by two array

Tags: mysql, sql

`select * from table where columnA = ? and columnB = ?`

the params are [[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']]
I want to get the result where columnA=1, columnB='a' and columnA=2, columnB='b' and columnA=3, columnB='c'
How can I achieve this in MySQL?

Comment: The query looks fine at least based on what you have told us.  What is the problem?

Comment: I am not sure whether it is fine. I use node.js mysql and I will have a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,I just find the answer.
`select * from table where (columnA, columnB) in ?`

while the param should be ((1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), ...)

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

This is solution

```
select * from table where 
     (columnA = 1 and columnB = 'a') OR
     (columnA = 2 and columnB = 'b') OR
     (columnA = 3 and columnB = 'c')
```

Comment: if columnA is in 1~26 and columnB is in 'a'~'z', then how to achieve this?